# How to see the image data of a JOGL Texture object?

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

When creating a Texture object in jogl, you can do this by passing the constructor a GL object and a TextureData object containing a Buffer with the image data. I do not know, however, how you can retrieve something like a TextureData object from an existing Texture object. Essentially, I want to fetch the image data of a Texture, preferrably in buffer form. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should simply keep a reference on the passed TextureData object instead of looking for a getter. The same Texture object can use different TextureData objects during its lifetime because you can call updateImage() or updateSubImage() later.